# Viewing PDF in Page Viewer Web Part in WSS 3.0, users are prompted to download, open or save

Tags: wss-3.0, pdf, page-viewer-web-part

Currently using WSS 3.0 and I am using page viewer web part to display a PDF file though when the page loads, users are prompted with the file download box to open or save the file.

Running Internet Explorer 8.

How can I get the PDF File to display without the File Download prompt?

Answer (score 1):

To open pdf file in browser use this code

```
                        WebClient client = new WebClient();
                        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData("address of pdf file");
                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
                        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
```

Comment: Thank you for the code though where do I insert it?  The PDF file is currently viewed via Page Viewer webpart.

Comment: Hi Marina no idea how you can done with page view webpart

but you can do it with CEWP

Please check this link

http://www.sharepointsharon.com/2010/08/embedding-pdfs/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if MiME type (Pdf) are added to the IIS .
By default,it will be blocked to open directly in SharePoint .

If it happens only for specific users then it must be IE Settings  .

Thanks,
Aravind.